# Printing 0 twice

Tags: python

I coded this program to find the factorial of a number. When I tried it with the number 0 it would print twice but when I use any other number it just works fine.

```
def factorial_num(factorial):
  num = int(input("Write a number to figure out his factorial"))
  if num == 0:
    print ("The factorial of 0 is 1")
  elif num < 0:
    print ("Negative numbers don't have a factorial")
  else:
    for i in range (1, num + 1):
     factorial = factorial*i
  print ("The factorial of", num, "is", factorial)

factorial_num(1)
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: It's because you have a `print` call on the last line of your function, which applies to all input values, as well as one specific to `0` on the 4th line of your snippet. (It also doesn't make much sense to pass the function a parameter, `factorial`, and then more or less ignore it. If you're taking the input from the user - `num` here - the function doesn't need to take any parameters.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically the issue here has to do with indentation.

If you look at your **if** block there are 3 options. With any given number only 1 of the: if, elif, else will be executed, then the code will continue running after the if block.

When you input 0 the code executes the

> if num == 0:
>
> print ("The factorial of 0 is 1")

block (Hence printing the result once) then continues after it.

After the if block there is another print that gets executed always (Hence the second print)

**What you can do to fix that:**

Indent the last print so its in the *else* part of the block *or* Completely remove the first if part and modify the block so the 0 is included on the *else* part.